# Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments?

Tags: ios, swift

Just started playing around with swift trying to write some code that detects if there is an internet connection. I am getting Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments on the last line. What am I doing wrong?

```
class func hasConnectivity() -> Bool {
  let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
  let networkStatus: NetworkStatus = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus()
  return networkStatus != NotReachable
}
```

Comment: looks like you're working on the Apple 'Reachability' sample! how did you implement your `NetworkStatus` enum?

Answer (score 1):

One way to return the result you are looking for would be to switch on `networkStatus`:

```
switch networkStatus {
case .NotReachable:
    return false
default:
    return true
}
```

Comment: any updates? this should have solved it for you - switching on enum cases like this is how I've seen it done throughout The Swift Programming Language book

Answer (score 1):

You can use the raw value of the enum:

```
class func hasConnectivity() -> Bool {
    let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    let networkStatus: Int = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value
    return networkStatus != 0
}
```

`NotReachable` always has a value of 0 so you can check against that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return networkStatus != .NotReachable`